# Number of distinct light on/off patterns that give the same total number of lights on at each time interval

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I am investigating the following problem

Suppose there are a bunch of lights in a room. Let $[n]=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and suppose we have a function $f:[n]\to \Bbb N$ that records the total number of lights that are turned on at time $i$ for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. At each time step, any light can be either on or off. For each light, we can record its on/off schedule as a binary string of length $n$, where $0$ and $1$ indicate 'off' and 'on' at time $i$, respectively.

I would like to find out the number of distinct sets of light patterns that would give the same function $f$ that records the total that are turned on at any one time interval. By "distinct" I mean unique up to relabeling of the set of lights. e.g., if $n=3$ and we have two lights $L_1,L_2$, then I would regard the sequences given by $L_1:111, L_2:101$ and $L_1:101, L_2:111$ as the same pattern.

The number of lights is allowed to vary from at least $m = \max_{1 \leq i \leq n} f(i)$ to at most $A=\sum_{1 \leq i \leq n} f(i)$.

**Example**. Suppose $n=3$ and $f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=1$. Then if we have $2$ lights, the number of distinct patterns that align with $f$ is two, which are given by $111,010$ and $110,011$. However, it quickly becomes tedious to compute this by brute force for more than $2$ lights.

**Attempt**. What I have managed to do so far is count the number of light patterns, assuming the lights are considered to each be distinct. In this case, I think the number of such patterns should be given by
$$\sum_{k=m}^A \prod_{i=1}^n C(k, f(i)),$$
since at any time step with $k$ available lights, there are exactly $C(k,f(i))$ ways to choose $f(i)$ out of $k$ lights to be turned on at that time step. Thus the total number of patterns for each fixed $k$ is given by the product, and we just sum these up over the possible values of $k$.

**Question.** The above method is vastly overcounting, since many of the patterns could be essentially the same. Indeed, I have no idea how to count this when we want only the patterns that are unique up to relabeling of the lights. How can one approach this?

**Edit 1.** I thought of a simpler way to formulate the question. With the function $f$ as above and $k \geq \max_{1 \leq i \leq n}f(i)$ fixed, my question reduces to: how many distinct sets of $k$ binary strings of length $n$ can be made such that for each fixed digit $i$, the sum of all the strings' $i^{\mathrm{th}}$ digit is $f(i)$?